# Gitlab Remote Repository (locally-hosted)

Tags: installation, gitlab, private

I'm new to Git and Gitlab. I downloaded and installed Gitlab to my PC so I could have a private Git repository. I would like like to ask a few things regarding git-data in my private Gitlab setup (local only).

1. I was able to find my project name in the gitlab repository. It has some files/folders inside but I couldn't find the source code I pushed. I could see HEAD, INFO, etc. I was expecting to find my project folder which I pushed to this remote repository containing my source codes. Am I wrong to expect a copy of my project folder here with the source codes? Or is my pushed source code being stored in a compiled manner hence I couldn't find it?
2. Security-wise, can I assume that Gitlab doesn't send or push any of my code elsewhere in the Internet?﻿

Comment: 1. http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/, 2. Community edition is open source, you can check if you want to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for providing me links. based on my understanding of it, it looks like I should not be expecting a working copy of my source code in the remote repository as it does not maintain a working tree. This is because no one is supposed to make direct file / code edits in there.